# Contact form doesn't sending data to Email

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, email

I am working with PHP contact form to send contact-form data to my Email. My code is correct because I am not getting any error, even I am getting an Email sending a successful message but I didn't get an Email in my Email id.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
  <table width="450px">
  <tr>
      <td valign="top">
         <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
         <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td valign="top"">
         <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
         <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td valign="top">
         <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
         <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
      </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td valign="top">
        <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
        <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td valign="top">
        <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
        <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here is PHP Code:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

    function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you 
   submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
     }


// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you 
  submitted.');       
    }



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

   if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
     $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be 
   valid.<br />';
     }

  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be 
   valid. 
  <br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
   $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid. 
  <br 
   />';
   }

     if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
     $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid. 
    <br />';
     }

   if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
   died($error_message);
  }

  $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


  function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

 // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
  ?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php

}
?>
```

Please check this code and let me know what am I doing wrong there.

Comment: firstly remove @ from @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); and check your code for errors.

Comment: did you check the Spam in your mail?

Comment: Sir i remove @ and check i get this message "Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon." but i didn't get any email in my email id with filled form details.

Comment: yes sir i checked in spam too but there is also no mail recieved.

Comment: can anyone help to solve this??????

Comment: already try using PHPMailer?

Comment: Are you trying to run this in localhost or in your server?

Comment: i am  checking it on my live server